# Programming language suggestion for Windows app to connect to Sybase database

Tags: c#, c++, database

I am writing a Windows application that will connect to a Sybase database through an ODBC connection.
It will dynamically create a SQL statement based off of selections by the user in the GUI. 
It needs to be fast (1M+ records sometimes) and have the ability to export to Excel, or some other reporting tool (graphs, etc) 
What would be the best programming language to write this in?
I am leaning towards C#, I have experience writing in C#, C++ and VB; however I only have intermediate experience, not an expert by any means. 
I'm open to learning new languages if they offer advantages over the ones I listed perviously.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Off topic: Why are you using ODBC rather than a Sybase ADO.NET provider?

Comment: There is already an ODBC connection on the machine for another application, but I will look into an ADO, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the .Net languages (C#, Managed C++ and VB) have access to the same runtime library.  C# and VB are both simpler than Managed C++, and personally I prefer C# to VB (but that's a matter of taste).

You might also want to consider Java as it's also used extensively in enterprise applications that for database transactions.  It can be used to create CSV files that you can use in Excel or some other analysis / visualization application.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider Powerbuilder. It has a special relationship with Sybase ("native drivers specifically built for Sybase.." see http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerbuilder).
The syntax is similar to VB, and should be easy to get used to.
The newer versions have excellent report features, such as graphing, charting etc ...